# Database design: foreign keys and normalization

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm new to database design so please bear with me. I'm using PHP and MySQL.
I have a 'movies' table that contains some details about a movie. This includes genres, which have an (if I understand correctly) many to many relationship with movies, implying a single movie can belong to different genres and a single genre can belong to different movies.

From what I gather about database design, storing this kind of relationship in one table is not a good idea as it will either violate First Normal form or Second Normal form rules. 
How would I design my tables to avoid this; would I have to create a table for each genre separately or... ?

This leads my to my next question: separate tables need to have foreign keys to identify which information belongs to what row. In theory, if I had a unique key identifying each movie which I would then like to use to identify a director in a separate table, how would I create this relationship in MySQL?

Thank you for your time - if I've made anything unclear please let me know and I will try my best to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This includes genres, which have an (if I understand correctly) many
>   to many relationship with movies, implying a single movie can belong
>   to different genres and a single genre can belong to different movies.

That's right.

> From what I gather about database design, storing this kind of
>   relationship in one table is not a good idea

Right. You're looking for something loosely along these lines.

```
create table movies (
  movie_id integer primary key
  -- other columns
);

create table genres (
  genre varchar(15) primary key
  -- other columns?
);

create table movie_genres (
  movie_id integer not null,
  genre varchar(15) not null,
  primary key (movie_id, genre),
  foreign key (movie_id) references movies (movie_id),
  foreign key (genre) references genres (genre)
);
```

For directors, assuming there is only one director per movie, you can use this instead of the movies table above

```
create table movies (
  movie_id integer primary key,
  director_id integer not null,
  foreign key (director_id) references directors (director_id) -- not shown.
  -- other columns
);
```

Comment: Thank you for a great, comprehensive answer and thanks especially for covering the foreign key question.

Answer (score 2):

You need one table Movies, one table Genres and one table Movies_and_Genres. The first two contain unique primary keys which you can create using the mysql autoincrement field type. The third table contains pairs of those primary keys.

```
create table movies (id integer not null primary key auto_increment, title ... );
create table genres (id integer not null primary key auto_increment, genre ... );
create table movies_and_genres (id_movie integer not null, id_genre integer not null);
```

As for the directors, this is a question of data modeling. If a movie can have more than one director, then you need a directors and a movies_and_directors table. Otherwise you need only the directors table and a director column in the movies table.

Answer (score 2):

you need/should use [junction tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

*table* movie:

```
| id | title | rating |
-----------------------
| 1  | foo   |   5    |
| 2  | bar   |   4    |
```

*table* genre:

```
| id | name    | 
----------------
| 1  | comedy  |
| 2  | romance |
```

*table* director:

```
| id | name    | 
----------------
| 1  | hello   |
| 2  | world   |
```

*table* movie_genre:

```
| id | movie_id | genre_id |
----------------------------
| 1  |     1    |     1    |
| 2  |     1    |     2    |
| 3  |     2    |     1    |
```

*table* movie_director:

```
| id | movie_id | director_id |
-------------------------------
| 1  |     1    |     1       |
| 2  |     2    |     1       |
| 3  |     2    |     2       |
```

Answer (score 2):

You're quite right, what you need here is to have a table of movies (e.g. `tbl_movies`);

```
pk    id
      name
      ... etc
```

a table for genres (eg `tbl_genres`);

```
pk    id
      name
      ... etc
```

and a table linking the two (eg `tbl_movie_genres`);

```
fk    id_movies
fk    id_genres
```

You can either set the pk of the `tbl_movie_geners` to be the two foreign keys, or you can set a standalone pk (e.g `id` like in the `tbl_movies` and `tbl_genres` tables above).

this way you can list as many genres per movies and they're linked through the `tbl_movie_genres` table; eg:

```
tbl_movies:
id    name
1     Movie 1
2     Movie 2

tbl_genres:
id    name
1     Horror
2     Action
3     Rom Com

tbl_movie_genres
id_movies    id_genres
1            3
2            1
2            2
```

Would show you that 'Movie 1' is a rom com and 'Movie 2' is an action horror.

Answer (score 1):

To satisfy the many-many relationship use a join table that holds foreign keys to both the movie and genre tables:

```
MOVIE
-----
ID (PK)

GENRE
-----
ID (PK)

MOVIE_GENRE
-----------
MOVIE_ID (FK that references MOVIE(ID))
GENRE_ID (FK that references GENRE(ID))
```

Here the `MOVIE` table has a primary key of `ID`, the `GENRE` table has a primary key of `ID`, and the `MOVIE_GENRE` table has two foreign key references: one to `MOVIE.ID` and another to `GENRE.ID`.  The primary key for `MOVIE_GENRE` could either be the composite key of (`MOVIE_ID`,`GENRE_ID`) as that will be unique but you could use a synthetic key as well.

For dealing with the director table and relationship, if it is a one-to-many relationship (one director for many movies), simply add a foreign key to the `MOVIE` table:

```
DIRECTOR
--------
ID (PK)

MOVIE
-----
ID (PK)
DIRECTOR_ID (FK TO DIRECTOR(ID))
```

If the off chance you need to support another many-to-many relationship (many directors for many movies), use the join table approach like above.